# A function that returns a global variable

Tags: python, function, scope, global-variables

Is there a way to write a function that returns a global variable (creating the variable inside the function and returning it outside, globally)? I can't assign the variable before the function call because I'm using it on tkinter, therefore, it's on a While loop.

Comment: What does it mean to "return[s] a global variable"?

Comment: You can return *values*, not variables. Are you trying to *set* the value of a global variable inside a function? That's possible, though not usually recommended.

Comment: @ScottHunter I mean like, for example:
I don't have the variable X created yet, so:
`createX():
     x = 2
     return x`

That would return the value 2, but I actually needed the variable x to manipulate it

Comment: How does a `while` loop prevent you from assigning a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can mark a variable within a function as global using `global`. You can also return the value of the variable.

```py
def f():
    global x

    x = 1

    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a function can `set` a global variable but *cannot* return any local variable/ value that can impact a global state.

Generally, global variables are bad and make it really hard to reason about your program. Try your best to use *pure* functions with only local state

Comment: What does "return a global variable" even mean?

Comment: It have no idea, but it is impossible. What I understood is that the OP just trying to set a global state to pass it between differnt parts of the program

Comment: How do you know it is impossible if you can't even say what it *is*?

Comment: modifying the globals() directly is ugly as hell and even worse then returning a value and assigning that

Comment: @PatrickArtner I more meant *"cannot return one"* is not clear in it's meaning, [TIO](https://repl.it/repls/StaidAngryRouter). You can clearly return globals

Comment: @Nick show me how you can write a `return ???` that is global?

Comment: @iTech See above in TIO link

Comment: That's no difference from what I meant by `setting` global variable which you can definitely return. But what I meant if there is no global variable to start with ad per the OP question, then there is no way a `return` statement will impact a global state

Comment: @iTech *"But what I meant if there is no global variable to start with ad per the OP question, then there is no way a return statement will impact a global state"* - Then write that in your answer ;) because as it stands it's not clear what "cannot return one" is meant to mean

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, here is an example from a data science project I am writing.

```
_train_ds = None
_val_ds = None


def get_ds(split: str):
    def _get_ds():
        return CellExpressionGraphOptimized(split)

    if split == 'train':
        global _train_ds
        if _train_ds is None:
            _train_ds = _get_ds()
        return _train_ds
    elif split == 'validation':
        global _val_ds
        if _val_ds is None:
            _val_ds = _get_ds()
        return _val_ds
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError()


def train_model():
    # ...
    train_ds = get_ds('train')
    val_ds = get_ds('val')
    # ...
```

## Discussion

I disagree that global variables are wrong and are a bad coding practice. It depends of what code you are writing.
In my case I am training some machine learning models and the function `train_model()` is called by a library that calls it automatically many times during a model selection procedure. The variables `_train_ds` and `_val_ds` are some in-memory datasets that I don't want to create unnecessarily (I want them to be reused among various calls of the function `train()`), and here a global variable is a very transparent, and efficient, solution.